# How can I set a default font family in Kobo Aura H2O?

Tags: ebook-readers, kobo, font-rendering, customization

> It is not that I need any extra font in my Kobo Aura H2O, because I have added several extra fonts into /fonts directory in my device.

I want —if possible— to change the family font (one that includes Bold, Italics, Serif, San-Serif and Monospace styles/fonts) as the default font family. I want to do this so I can read pleasanty some ebooks that I made.

I explain my self: when I make epubs I define a monospace font setting in CSS for `<em>` tags, and of ocurse I use italics for `<i>` tags, bold for `<b>` tags, headings, and other stuff. But I have not embedded any font into my epub because of my editorial requisites do not allow me to do that. This is something that I cannot override, unfortunately.

When reading in my Kobo Aura H2O I like to choose «Default Editor» as my preferred font, so I can see the fonts defined in my epub. No overriding settings.

I would like to choose PT fonts (PT Sans, PT Serif, PT mono) as my default Kobo font family, for example, because of readibility issues ans because they are free to use. I think if I choose this family font in my Kobo then I will get displayed every tag correctly according to my CSS (or am I mistankingly assuming so?)

When I open my Kobo font settings, I see Georgia font as the default font, and **no** Monospace font in those words that I know are in `<em>` tags (Kobo uses italics for both `<em>` and `<i>` tags!!! which is unacceptable to me).

So, how can I change this settings?
I have no fear in patching my Kobo (though it would be my first time), if that's what is needed, ;D

Comment: Tumbleweed is not the kind of badge that I feel ok to earn… but that's what it is :(